# Can android be the host to a USB device?

Tags: android, usb

I have a USB device and want to build a nice graphical interface for it. Is it possible to connect the USB device to Android, have Android be the host, and communicate with it and build a UI? If so, which libraries would allow me to do this? And if not, what alternative workarounds are there? I would prefer a wired connection for reliability.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. I have personally used an USBc to USB cable to hook up everything from a keyboard and mouse to an external monitor. Some phones/devices may not have a data port on the external USB port or the chips needed for external monitors but android itself has USB drivers built in.

I think this question remained unanswered for so long because it's so easy to google the android developer page that should answer your question in specifics [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host). It's the developer guide for using android as a USB host.